# How to horizontally center align li in ul?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center list elements inside an unsorted list (inside a div). However, the li elements are not centered inside the ul box.

Running the following code shows that the ul red box is in the centre of the viewport. However, the red boxes around the three list items are shifted towards the right, instead of in the center. What should I do to make the three list items appear in the center of the ul box?

```css
h1.mainhead {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
.navigation ul {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class="mainhead">Page under construction</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inspect the `<ul>` element, there might be some padding there.. :)

Comment: So I added padding-left: 10px and padding-right: 10px; to <ul>. This has solved the problem. Is this the generally accepted way of doing this? And thanks for solving a problem I've been stuck on for 2 hours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the developer tools in your browser.
2. Inspect the list and the list items
3. Find where there is some spacing you don't want

[image]

… then remove it:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yep. You can use reset css. The idea behind reset is that all elements have predefined styles (included in web browsers)... they are reset and make them look the same in all browsers. Find most used [here](http://cssreset.com/). Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

There is browser default `padding` on the `ul` tag, reset that it should be then centered.

```
ul {padding-left:0;}
```